# Partitioning Datetime and Date data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one small question for partitioning table.
I have created a partition function on `Date` datatype, most of the table covers under it but some big table have to `DataTime` data type.
So the question is how can i use both data types in singe partition function and scheme? Or how can I handle this situation?

Appreciated your Help and Support.

Comment: I don't understand the situation. Is this one table or are there multiple tables that use your partitioning function? If there are e.g. two tables with two datatypes to partition on, use two different partitioning functions.

Comment: Hi I have multiple table and for that many of have the Date data type and couple of have the DateTime Data Type. and I have created only one Partition function with Date Data type. so what should I do with DateTime Data type? Do I have to create new partition function for that even?